# Android Bitmap Linear Interpolation Blending

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, blend, alphablending

I need to be able to blend two bitmaps together using a linear interpolation (or average). This is a fairly simple operation, but even using native code to manually apply it to each pixel is too slow.

How can I accomplish this? Is there any way to accomplish this using shaders without swapping my entire engine to openGL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Porter-Duff filtering with a Paint object to get the performance you want, even without using ndk. It tends to be pretty fast.

Show us your code and someone can probably provide a more specific answer.

Comment: I have looked through the standard PorterDuff modes have yet to find a way to combine them to achieve what I want. Any code is really just going to be standard bitmap rendering(canvas), there isn't anything special about the rest.